# How to interpret this equation?

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

I am trying to work out an equation without a description. I need to figure out what is this equation exactly and how to interpret its results. Here it is:

Variables:

$ u_1, u_2, u_3,... u_n [m] $

$ s_1, s_2, s_3,... s_n [m] $

$ v_1, v_2, v_3,... v_n [\frac{m}{s}] $

$ V, U [\frac{m}{s}] $

Calculations:

$ u_1 = s_1 \cdot \frac{(V - v_2) \cdot (V - v_3) \cdot ... \cdot (V - v_n)}
{(v_1 - v_2) \cdot (v_1 - v_3) \cdot ... \cdot (v_1 - v_n)} $

$ u_2 = s_2 \cdot \frac{(V - v_1) \cdot (V - v_3) \cdot ... \cdot (V - v_n)}
{(v_2 - v_1) \cdot (v_2 - v_3) \cdot ... \cdot (v_2 - v_n)} $

$ u_3 = s_3 \cdot \frac{(V - v_1) \cdot (V - v_2) \cdot ... \cdot (V - v_n)}
{(v_3 - v_1) \cdot (v_3 - v_2) \cdot ... \cdot (v_3 - v_n)} $

$ \vdots $

$ u_n = s_n \cdot \frac{(V - v_1) \cdot (V - v_2) \cdot ... \cdot (V - v_n)}
{(v_n - v_1) \cdot (v_n - v_2) \cdot ... } $

$ U = u_1 + u_2 + u_3 + ... + u_n $

In this example the $ s $ and $ u $ elements are lengths and $ v $ are velocities. $ v $ and $ s $ are velocity->distance pairs representing breaking distance of an object for a certain speed of that object. $ V $ is the current velocity of the object. What are $ u $ and $ U $?

I would appreciate all help regarding understanding this.

Comment: This is just using a polynomial to fit the recorded pairs. The notation and presentation is non-standard, but U is an $n-1$ degree interpolating polynomial and $u_k$’s are the Lagrange basis polynomials weighted by the distance they are interpolating. For more: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: @adfriedman You sir have made my day.